# Pasting a string matrix row-wise with a string vector

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, paste

I am trying to concatenate `multcompView` letters with summary data into a matrix. I am using a `for loop` to run through the individual summary matrix cells and concatenate these with their respective letters. I am almost there but my matrix outputs both the original data and the pasted data (see below).

Function:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(X1))
  tableRow = matrix(c(tableRow,paste(tableRow[i],letters$Letters[i],sep = "")),nrow = 1)
```

Where:
 `X1` is my summary table, `tableRow` is the first row of `X1`, and
`letters` contains the letter I want to concatenate with.

Returns:

```
[1,] "5.53 ± 0.77" "6.72 ± 1.18" "5.12 ± 0.44"
 "5.24 ± 0.41" "5.53 ± 0.77a" "6.72 ± 1.18a" "5.12 ± 0.44a" "5.24 ± 0.41a"
```

Desired output:

```
[1,]  "5.53 ± 0.77a" "6.72 ± 1.18a" "5.12 ± 0.44a" "5.24 ± 0.41a"
```

Comment: Can add data if needed. Didn't want to clutter up the question!

Comment: @ZheyuanLi No, many columns, but I thought I would try to tackle the first row first.

Comment: A good idea but no cigar.  :)  I am creating the matrix row by row as the different columns must be concatenated with different letters. Your suggestion not only adds a letter to all rows, but that pesky first line of the original, non-concatenated data remains!

Comment: Okay, I will have a play around and see what I come up with. Will get back to you soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do all the work:

```
## example matrix
set.seed(0); X <- round(matrix(runif(12), nrow = 4, ncol = 3), 2)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 0.90 0.91 0.66
# [2,] 0.27 0.20 0.63
# [3,] 0.37 0.90 0.06
# [4,] 0.57 0.94 0.21

matrix(paste0(X, letters[1:4]), nrow = nrow(X))

#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
# [1,] "0.9a"  "0.91a" "0.66a"
# [2,] "0.27b" "0.2b"  "0.63b"
# [3,] "0.37c" "0.9c"  "0.06c"
# [4,] "0.57d" "0.94d" "0.21d"
```

For your data, you can do:

```
matrix(paste0(X1, letters$Letters), nrow = nrow(X1))
```

---

**Remark 1**

My example here has some defect. You already have `X1` as a character matrix, while my example `X` is numeric. When doing `paste0()`, numerical value `0.90` becomes `"0.9"` (because `as.character(0.90)` gives `"0.9"`). For your data there will be no such behaviour.

**Remark 2**

Oh, I actually find a way to avoid such behaviour.

```
X <- format(X)

#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
# [1,] "0.90" "0.91" "0.66"
# [2,] "0.27" "0.20" "0.63"
# [3,] "0.37" "0.90" "0.06"
# [4,] "0.57" "0.94" "0.21"
```

Then doing `paste0()` is OK:

```
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]   
# [1,] "0.90a" "0.91a" "0.66a"
# [2,] "0.27b" "0.20b" "0.63b"
# [3,] "0.37c" "0.90c" "0.06c"
# [4,] "0.57d" "0.94d" "0.21d"
```

Comment: It worked!! Amazing!! Thank you so much.  :)
To keep in line with the question, my final line looks like this:
`for (i in 1:nrow(X1))
  tableRow = matrix(paste0(X1[,2],letters$Letters[i]),nrow=1)`

Comment: You are right, thanks. This is probably because of all the steps taken to get to this point. I thought if I pasted all that it would be a terrible mess. But I also thought the for loop might be causing problems and someone might pick up on that.